# PowerBI: Comparing a filterd table against a variable string is returning an empty table

Tags: string, filter, powerbi, comparison, dax

Please see the code below for a Power BI table in DAX:

```
TABLE1 =

VAR ParticipantOneParticipantId =     
SELECTEDVALUE(
    ParticipantOneDetails[ParticipantId]
)

RETURN 
FILTER(
    ParticipantOneMeetings, 
    ParticipantOneMeetings[ParticipantId] = ParticipantOneParticipantId
)
```

I am fetching a value for ParticipantId from a sliced table called ParticipantOneDetails and setting ParticipantOneParticipantId to it.

In the next step I am trying to filter the table ParticipantOneMeetings based on its column ParticipantId comparing it against ParticipantOneParticipantId.

The problem is that the resulting table is coming out empty even though I know that ParticipantOneParticipantId must have a value and the ParticipantOneMeetings table also has values. I verified by comparing against a hard-coded string.

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong? Is comparing this way not legal?

Comment: On further testing, it appears that the following expression in the above cocde is all the time getting set to the default string value of "1100" and not correctly setting the first part of the expression.

VAR ParticipantOneParticipantId = SELECTEDVALUE(ParticipantOneDetails[ParticipantId], "1100")

Comment: Is there any Slicer for column "ParticipantOneDetails[ParticipantId]" from where you are picking value using SELECTEDVALUE?

Comment: Yes, there is a slicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the following measure to the table output:

```
MeetingsAttendedByBothParticipants = 
countrows(
    INTERSECT(
        VALUES(ParticipantOneMeetings[Name]), 
        VALUES(ParticipantTwoMeetings[Name])
    )
)
```

The above provides an intersection on output of two sliced meeting tables. This results in a list of meetings that both persons attend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the process you are trying. A calculated/custom tables and columns are static. They always refresh when the data set is refreshed. They do not interact dynamically with the slicer value. So it is impossible to get data from a slicer dynamically for a Custom Table generation.

Now, your requirement of creating a new table based on slicer value is not completely clear to me. As what you are trying, is a simple filtered output of your table "**ParticipantOneMeetings**" after applying the Slicer. If you have relation between your 2 tables using column "**ParticipantId**", change in Slicer will automatically filter out values in **ParticipantOneMeetings** table. Why you wants to hold this same filtered values in a new Custom table is really a mater here to know for finding appropriate solution for you.

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit more complex. What I am doing is selecting names of two different persons from two different slicers. Then I want to figure out all the meetings they are attending. No problem up to this point and I implemented this as you pointed out in your suggestion. However, the goal is to figure out which meetings they attend together. I think this would require the use of intersect. My plan was to figure out all the meetings attended by the two persons separately and then somehow find an intersection. I might be making it more difficult than it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: The code at the top was my workaround. I was going to use it to obtain the meetings list for each person based on the persons selected in the slicers and then add additional logic to obtain an intersection.

Comment: As an additional note, as suggested by you, I am able to obtain the meetings attended by each participant separately in ParticipantOneMeetings and ParticipantTwoMeetings, respectively. The problem is that the intersect (or even the union) of ParticipantOneMeetings and ParticipantTwoMeetings results in an empty table.

Comment: Hi @Learner, the best option is show your sample data from source table, and then explain what you want to achieve and how.

Comment: I have already solved the problem. Please see my solution above under Answers. Thanks.